# how do you run an application on window server (standard edition) 2012 R2 on more than 64 logical processors

Tags: windows

I have a server whose operating system is windows server 2012 R2 (standrd edition) the processors are two xeon e5 2699 v3. With hyperthreading enabled I have 72 logical processors. the environment variables shows number of processors as 36 instead of the expected 72. Task master shows 2 sockets, 36 cores and 72 logical processors. The resource monitor shows two numa groups with 36 cpus in each. The setaffinity from the task master shows two groups (group 0 and group 1). Only one group affinity can be set at one time by this method.

The issue is how can I ensure that all 72 logical processors are engaged for any application that is run on the machine. Currently any application only runs in one group, one numa group and 50% of the cpu.

I have read the msdn Supporting Systems That Have More Than 64 Processors but that document was written in 2008 and specifically relates to windows 7. How relevant that is for windows server 2012 R2 perhaps someone can tell me. The same could be said for the msdn documents Processor Groups and Numa Support. All these documents need to be updated for the most current server operation systems of today.

I would want any application to be capable of setting all the necessary requirements in order to be able to access and fully use of 72 logical processors, whether the Group Processors, setprocessaffinitymask  or setthreadaffinitymask or the Numa support for systems with more than 64 logical processors need to be set I am unsure.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that? It may _signififcantly_ slow down your application!

Comment: yes I do. I have an application that is performance critical and needs all the processing power it can muster to complete the task in the shortest possible time.

Comment: Applications need to be modified to support using large numbers of processors as the MSDN document mentions. This usually also includes any DLLs they load.